# Irreducible Module in $\mathbb Q$ and $\mathbb C$

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

Consider $V=(x,y,z)$ in $\mathbb{Q}^3$ and $\mathbb Q[X]$ a polynomial ring.
Define $\mathbb Q[X]$-module by $X(x,y,z)=(-5z+5y,x+z,z)$.
How can I show that V is irreducible $\mathbb Q[X]$-module?

Now if I change $\mathbb Q$ to $\mathbb C$, how is it decomposed to direct sums of irreducible modules?

Answer (score 2):

Actually $V$ is not irreducible (unless I made a mistake in my calculations).

Call $u$ the endomorphism of $V$ given by the action of $X$. You can easily compute the characteristic polynomial of $u$ (using the fact that the last line of the matrix has only one non-zero term, for instance), and you get $\chi(T) = (T-1)(T^2-5)$.

Thus $V = Ker(u-Id)\oplus Ker(u^2-5Id)$ is a module decomposition.

You can find the components by computing the usual way the kernel of $u-Id$ and $u^2-5Id$.

Over $\mathbb{C}$, since the characteristic polynomial has distinct roots, $u$ will be diagonalizable with eigenvalues $1$, $\pm \sqrt{5}$. You can find the eigenlines for these last two values by computing the kernel of $u\pm \sqrt{5}Id$.